# Reading Already Trained SMO Model Gives StreamoutofException Error

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, smo

I have trained the `svm` model in the `smo` and write it to a file using SerializationHelper.

when I try to read the model to classify it gives the following error:

> Problem found: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 47656E65

Here is the line that gives the error:

```
classifier = (Classifier) SerializationHelper.read(strModel);
```

EDITED:

```
    Instances inst = Filter.useFilter(data, vectorizer);
    inst.setClassIndex(0);
    SMO svm = new SMO();
    RBFKernel kernal = new RBFKernel();
    svm.setKernel(kernal);
    svm.buildClassifier(filteredDate);
    SerializationHelper.write("SMO_samp.model", svm);
```

Comment: How did you save the model? Any code snippet is good.

Comment: Hi  Rushdi Shams i have edited my post above inserted the code..

Answer (score 0):

For the error, [this](http://list.waikato.ac.nz/pipermail/wekalist/2008-August/040649.html) might be helpful.

This is a completely working example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Random;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes;
import weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM;
import weka.classifiers.functions.SMO;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.SerializationHelper;


public class CodeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        BufferedReader breader = null;
        breader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("iris.arff"));

        Instances train_data = new Instances (breader);
        breader.close();
        train_data.setClassIndex(train_data.numAttributes() -1);

        SMO smo = new SMO();
        smo.buildClassifier(train_data);

        SerializationHelper s = new SerializationHelper();
        s.write("SMO_samp.model", smo);
        Classifier c = new SMO();
        c = (Classifier) s.read("SMO_Samp.model");
        Evaluation evaluation = null;
        evaluation = new Evaluation (train_data);
        evaluation.crossValidateModel(c, train_data, 10, new Random(1));
        System.out.println(evaluation.toSummaryString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rushdi shams it helps a lot..besides can u tell how to classify a new instance (predicting new abstract) . if u give me examples with tokenizer, and using string to word vector and Filter options